# Flatten out y-matrix and repeat x-vector

Tags: numpy

So I have a vector `x` and a matrix `y` where `y[i] = [f(x[i]),f(x[i]),f(x[i])...]` is a row of experimental values of `f` at `x`. I need to flatten out y so that I have two vectors with `y[i] = f(x[i])`. Here's what I'm using now:

```
x = np.ravel([[xx]*y.shape[1] for xx in x]); y = np.ravel(y)
```

Is there a cleaner/faster way?

Answer (score 1):

You could just use [`np.repeat`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.repeat.html) -

```
x = x.repeat(y.shape[1])
```